# How to use the setAttribute method?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I'm just learning JavaScript and I want to just figure out why this isn't working can anyone help me? I'm expecting on load that image1 will be replaced with image2.

```
<! DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Slide show</title>
 </head>

 <body>
<h1>Pictures</h1>
    <img src="image1.jpg" id="first">
    <img src="image2.jpg" id="second">

<script type="text/javascript" src="Slideshow.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the javascript:

```
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var image2 = document.getElements("second");
var slideit = function() {

if (first === image1.jpg) {
    first.setAttribute("src", image2);
}
}

onload.slideit();
```

Comment: *"i want to just figure out why this isn't working"* What doesn't work? What do you expect and what happens? **Describe your problem!** [Learn how to debug JavaScript](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820)

Comment: Generally it's simpler and more reliable to use DOM properties (e.g. `if(first.src == 'image1.jpg')` rather than *get/setAttribute*, which are a bit inconsistent and even buggy in some older browers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with this code

```
if (first === image1.jpg) {
```

try putting

```
if (first.getAttribute('src') === 'image1.jpg') {
```

And then perhaps also at the reassigning

```
first.setAttribute("src", image2.getAttribute('src'));
```

Also the variable image2 seems to be initialized wrongly

```
var image2 = document.getElementsById("second");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var image2 = document.getElementById("second");

var slideit = function() {

    if (first.getAttribute('src') == "image1.jpg") {
        first.setAttribute("src", image2.getAttribute('src'));
    }
}

onload.slideit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your this part of code is wrong

```
var image2 = document.getElements("second");
```

It should be :

```
var image2 = document.getElementById("second").getAttribute("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle between the two images, you could use the [*conditional operator* `? :`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12):

```
first.src = first.src == 'image1.jpg'? 'image2.jpg' : 'image1.jpg';
```

but that may not be what you want to do.